# How to update header.phtml with hardcoded image

Tags: magento-1.9, header-files, hardcode

I am trying to remove an image from a header.phtml file. It has been hard coded into the header.phtml in addition to the regular magento header image. I cannot access the image I want to delete through magento. I have found the line of code where it has been added to the header.phtml but don't know what the next step is to change this... can I delete the header.phtml file from our sftp and then re-upload it with the appropriate line of code deleted or will that ruin the whole site?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you have tried in `header.phtml`.

Comment: You will want to 'override' the header.phtml file into your custom theme directory, then change that.  Do not edit the base/default, default/default, or rwd/default template files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add the echo function " 
";
For example

```
<table border = "3">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <? php
             $ files = glob ("img / *");
             foreach ($ files as $ file) {
                 echo "<div class = 'divimages'>";
                 echo '<img src = "'. $ file. '" />';
                 echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Delete image' /> <br>";
                 echo "</ div>";
             }
             ?>
         </ td>
     </ tr>
</ table>
```

Comment: Try to find it in app / design / $ package_name / $ theme_name / template / page / html / header.phtml                                                                                                                        $package_name is the name of the package - e.g. base                                                    $theme_name is the name of the theme (usually default). This information I get from https://edubirdie.com/statistics-help. Find all these values in the admin panel - System -> Configuration -> General -> Design.